# Traceroute printing asterisk symbol

Tags: traceroute

I am trying to use `traceroute` unix program to find the route to a host.

I tried `traceroute www.google.com` and I end up seeing only asterisks printed. Examples on the internet uses the same command and it seems to work well. I tried increasing the `waitime` value using `-w` switch. Still does not work.

Answer (score 5):

Well, you get your answer almost a year later. I personally was wondering the same thing, so I did some googling and found
[this answer on webmasters.](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/17793/what-does-an-asterisk-star-in-traceroute-mean)

> If a packet is not acknowledged within the expected timeout, an asterisk is displayed.

Answer (score 4):

I found that `traceroute -I` gave more complete results.

```
   -I, --icmp
          Use ICMP ECHO for probes
```

Comment: Good! For me only with -I that this command seems to work right. Without -I, it tries until hop 30, even that the target is closer.